# Evaluating a math string in Corona Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I would like to evaluate a math string in my corona app. Right now I'm focusing on the trig functions, so let's let the example be the most difficult we're likely to face:

`local expr = "2sin(4pi+2)+7"`

My goal is for this to somehow be (either) evaluated as is with maybe a `pi --> math.pi` switch, or to even break it up. The breaking up would be much more difficult, however, since it COULD be as complicated a above, but could also just be `sin(1)`.

So I would prefer to stay as close to the python `eval(expr)` function as possible, but if that can't happen, I am flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to replace `sin` with `math.sin` (`pi` with `math.pi` and so on), add missing multiplications signs, and run it through `loadstring`, but `loadstring` is not available in Corona environment.

This means you will need to write your own parser for these expressions. I found a discussion on Corona forums that may help you as a starting point: [here](http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2011/09/14/evaluate-string), with some details and a demo [here](http://howto.oz-apps.com/2011/09/wip-eval-routine-for-coronasdk.html)

Comment: Jack Crenshaw has written a great tutorial on how to write an expression parser: http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/
Although it is quite old, I found it to be very helpful and not overly complicated...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, it is able to use the lua math functions without putting 'math.function' so just sqrt(100) works fine. I threw this together because I have seen this question asked way too many times. Hopes this helps :)

If you have any questions feel free to contact me at rayaman99@gmail.com

```
function evaluate(cmd,v) -- this uses recursion to solve math equations
    --[[ We break it into pieces and solve tiny pieces at a time then put them back together
        Example of whats going on
        Lets say we have "5+5+5+5+5"
        First we get this:
        5+5+5+5 +   5
        5+5+5   +   5
        5+5 +   5
        5   +   5
        Take all the single 5's and do their opperation which is addition in this case and get 25 as our answer
        if you want to visually see this with a custom expression, uncomment the code below that says '--print(l,o,r)'
    ]]
    v=v or 0
    local count=0
    local function helper(o,v,r)-- a local helper function to speed things up and keep the code smaller
        if type(v)=="string" then
            if v:find("%D") then
                v=tonumber(math[v]) or tonumber(_G[v]) -- This section allows global variables and variables from math to be used feel free to add your own enviroments
            end
        end
        if type(r)=="string" then
            if r:find("%D") then
                r=tonumber(math[r]) or tonumber(_G[r]) -- A mirror from above but this affects the other side of the equation
                -- Think about it as '5+a' and 'a+5' This mirror allows me to tackle both sides of the expression
            end
        end
        local r=tonumber(r) or 0
        if o=="+" then -- where we handle different math opperators
            return r+v
        elseif o=="-" then
            return r-v
        elseif o=="/" then
            return r/v
        elseif o=="*" then
            return r*v
        elseif o=="^" then
            return r^v
        end
    end
    for i,v in pairs(math) do
        cmd=cmd:gsub(i.."(%b())",function(a)
            a=a:sub(2,-2)
            if a:sub(1,1)=="-" then
                a="0"..a
            end
            return v(evaluate(a))
        end)
    end
    cmd=cmd:gsub("%b()",function(a)
        return evaluate(a:sub(2,-2))
    end)
    for l,o,r in cmd:gmatch("(.*)([%+%^%-%*/])(.*)") do -- iteration this breaks the expression into managable parts, when adding pieces into
        --print(":",l,o,r) -- uncomment this to see how it does its thing
        count=count+1 -- keep track for certain conditions
        if l:find("[%+%^%-%*/]") then -- if I find that  the lefthand side of the expression contains lets keep breaking it apart
            v=helper(o,r,evaluate(l,v))-- evaluate again and do the helper function
        else
            if count==1 then
                v=helper(o,r,l) -- Case where an expression contains one mathematical opperator
            end
        end
    end
    if count==0 then return (tonumber(cmd) or tonumber(math[cmd]) or tonumber(_G[cmd])) end
    -- you can add your own enviroments as well... I use math and _G
    return v
end
a=5
print(evaluate("2+2+2*2")) -- This still has work when it comes to pemdas; however, the use parentheses can order things!
print(evaluate("2+2+(2*2)"))-- <-- As seen here
print(evaluate("sqrt(100)"))
print(evaluate("sqrt(100)+abs(-100)"))
print(evaluate("sqrt(100+44)"))
print(evaluate("sqrt(100+44)/2"))
print(evaluate("5^2"))
print(evaluate("a")) -- that we stored above
print(evaluate("pi")) -- math.pi
print(evaluate("pi*2")) -- math.pi
```